# Plugin function to find pitch?

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is the function call when writing a Gazebo plugin to find out how much my model has tilted? Access angular Pose variables?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19841/plugin-function-to-find-pitch?/) by [MRhinelander](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5614/mrhinelander/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answer found here:
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19796/how-to-get-the-angle-value-of-the-base-link-of-a-floating-based-robot-in-gazebo9/

---

Originally posted by [MRhinelander](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5614/mrhinelander/) with karma: 5 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0